# Data sources in Azure Machine Learning Services

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service

What are the different data sources we can import data into Azure Machine Learning Services storage or notebook. I mean from Salesforce or any ERP or any website? As of now I have seen importing data using URL or getting it from data location in storage where notebook will also be stored.

I have not got anything to try on. I googled for different methods, but couldn't find relevant link. So I didn't try much there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question. You can import data from Azure Blob, Azure File, ADLS Gen1, ADLS Gen2, Azure SQL, Azure PostgreSQL. 
For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data

You can create an Azure ML Dataset for your training scenarios. Dataset can be created either from the data store mentioned above or from public urls.
For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-register-datasets